# On Android, I'm in (or not) in meta.SE

Tags: bug, android-app

After the switchover, I tried to post a bug report for Android from my tablet. I selected `meta.stackexchange.com`, and could see my earlier posts on meta.SO. I tried to ask an new question, and was informed that I have to join. OK, tried to join, was told I was already a member.